# Why is my Factory not getting instantiated/injected?

Tags: angularjs

Why is readingController not able to use the Romanize service? It always says Romanize is undefined inside the function. How can I get the service in scope?

```
var readingController = function (scope, Romanize){
    scope.currentMaterial = scope.sections[scope.sectionNumber].tutorials[scope.tutorialNumber].material;
    Romanize;
}

var app = angular.module('Tutorials', ['functions', 'tutorials']).controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.sectionNumber = 0;
    $scope.tutorialNumber = 0;
    $scope.questionNumber = 0;
    $scope.sections = sections;
    $scope.loadFromMenu = function (sec, tut, first) {
        if (tut === $scope.tutorialNumber && sec === $scope.sectionNumber && !first) {//if clicked on already playing tut
            return;
        } 
        if (tut !== undefined && sec !== undefined) {
            $scope.tutorialNumber = tut;
            $scope.sectionNumber = sec;
        }
        for (var x in sections) {
            sections[x].active = "inactive";
            for (var y in sections[x].tutorials){
                sections[x].tutorials[y].active = "inactive";
            }
        }
        var section = sections[$scope.sectionNumber];
        section.active = "active";
        section.tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].active = "active";
        $scope.questionNumber = 0;
        $scope.currentTutorialName = sections[$scope.sectionNumber].tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].name;
        $scope.$apply();
        if ($scope.sectionNumber === 0){
            readingController($scope, app.Romanize);
        }else if ($scope.sectionNumber === 1){
            conjugationController($scope);
        }
    };

    $scope.loadFromMenu(0,0, true);

    var conjugationController = function (){
        var loadNewVerbs = function (scope) {
            scope.currentVerbSet = scope.sections[scope.sectionNumber].tutorials[scope.tutorialNumber].verbs;
            if (scope.currentVerbSet === undefined) {
                alert("Out of new questions");
                return
            }
            scope.verbs = conjugate(scope.currentVerbSet[scope.questionNumber]);
            scope.correct = scope.verbs.conjugations[0].text;
            fisherYates(scope.verbs.conjugations);
            scope.$apply();
        };
        loadNewVerbs($scope);
        $scope.checkAnswer = function (answer) {
            if($scope.sectionNumber === 0 && $scope.tutorialNumber === 0 && $("video")[0].currentTime < 160){
                $scope.message = "Not yet!";
                $(".message").show(300).delay(900).hide(300);
                return;
            }
            answer.colorReveal = "reveal-color";
            if (answer.text === $scope.correct) { //if correct skip to congratulations          
                $scope.questionNumber++;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    loadNewVerbs($scope);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }, 2000);
            } else { //if incorrect skip to try again msg
                if ($scope.sectionNumber === 0 && $scope.tutorialNumber === 0) {
                    start(160.5);
                    pause(163.8)
                }
            }
        };
    };

});

app.factory('Romanize', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
      get: function(){
          $http.get(scope.sections[scope.sectionNumber].romanizeService).success(function(data) {
                $scope.romanized = data;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** based on comments/discussion below:

For a service to be instantiated, it has to be injected somewhere – not just anywhere – somewhere where Angular accepts injectables. Just inject it into your getAnswers controller – `.controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element, Romanize)` – then pass it to your "controller" function: `readingController($scope, Romanize)`.

Since I don't think readingController is a real Angular controller, you can name the arguments whatever you want, so `scope` should be fine.

---

Original attempt at an answer:

Inject `$scope` not `scope` into your controller:

```
var readingController = function ($scope, Romanize){
```

Then I don't get any errors: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4RCsuKNNOY6JoR8ZMnky?p=preview).

Comment: Isn't that just what it's called when it's already inside the controller? It's called here `if ($scope.sectionNumber === 0){readingController($scope, app.Romanize);` and that's where the injection occurs isn't it? Anyway, I tried changing it inside too and Romanize was still undefined :(

Comment: Is it the fact that the service is defined outside the main controller (getAnswers) but readingController is called from inside it? If so how do I make the service available inside getAnswers?

Comment: @Tules, the injection happens before the controller runs.  When controllers are defined this way, "[Inferring Dependencies](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)" requires specific names -- i.e., `$scope` must be used.  When you define a linking function, dependency injection is not involved, so you can call the first argument whatever you want.  Something else must be wrong, as Romanize is injected fine in my sample Plunker.  Can you post a plunker that doesn't work?

Comment: yeah but the function inside of the Romanize factory service never gets called

Comment: @Tules, I updated my original plunker with a console.log() -- the service is getting called.  You probably have to resolve some other errors.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BsjPGSSQ7QzTITwubxyy?p=preview so the service returns an object where the key "get" = a function in which my $http request sits. How do I trigger that function?

Comment: Ok on closer inspection I realize the only difference between what I'm doing and what ur doing is the markup, ur attaching the `readingController` to `ng-controller` whereas I'm trying to call it from within another controller, namely the `getAnswers` main controller. There is a an `if /else if` to check `$scope.sectionNumber`, it then calls the correct controller depending on which section you're on. `conjugationController` works fine but when `readingController` is called from inside the `else if` Romanize is always undefined. Why can it not access the service when called from the `else if`?

Comment: @Tules, okay, now I see what is going on.  For a service to be instantiated, it has to be injected somewhere -- not just anywhere -- somewhere where Angular accepts injectables.  Just inject it into your `getAnswers` controller -- `.controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element, Romanize)` -- then pass it to your "controller" function: `readingController($scope, Romanize)`.  Since I don't think `readingController` is a real Angular controller, you can name the arguments whatever you want, so `scope` should be fine.

Comment: wow, yeah that's done it :) Although I now have many more questions about how to pass variables from $scope to the service etc the original issue has been solved and I really should sleep! Thank you